# Trying to play video on a new background image in uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to play a video on a new background frame on clicking or tapping of image after video completed the old frame should visible again.Any help would be appreciated.

XAML

```
<Grid>
       <Grid.Background>
          <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images\1280x800 final file.png"/>
       </Grid.Background>
       <MediaElement x:Name="pSong"  Margin="30,30,30,30"
                     RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                     Canvas.ZIndex="1"
                     MediaEnded="Mend" />
       <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
       <StackPanel x:Name="LOfRhymes" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0">
            <RelativePanel x:Name="TTLS" Height="90px" BorderBrush="Black" 
                           BorderThickness="1" Tapped="TTLStap">                                   
                <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" FontSize="14" 
                            FontWeight="ExtraBold" 
                            RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"  
                            Margin="20,25"
                            Text="Rhymes"/>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="14"                                
                            RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                            Margin="20,15"
                            Text="Twinkle Twinkle Little Star"/>
                <Image Source="images\01.jpg"
                        RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                        Margin="0,10,80,0"
                        Width="100px"
                        Height="70px"
                        />
            </RelativePanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>                                              
</Grid>
```

C# code

```
private void TTLStap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pSong.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Videos/twinkle.mp4");
    pSong.AreTransportControlsEnabled = true;            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, the solution should be easy if you change the order of the elements and use `Visibility`:

```
<Grid>
       <Grid.Background>
          <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images\1280x800 final file.png"/>
       </Grid.Background>
       <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
       <StackPanel x:Name="LOfRhymes" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0">
            <RelativePanel x:Name="TTLS" Height="90px" BorderBrush="Black" 
                           BorderThickness="1" Tapped="TTLStap"> 
                <TextBlock Foreground="Blue" FontSize="14" 
                            FontWeight="ExtraBold" 
                            RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"  
                            Margin="20,25"
                            Text="Rhymes"/>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="14"  
                            RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                            Margin="20,15"
                            Text="Twinkle Twinkle Little Star"/>
                <Image Source="images\01.jpg"
                        RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                        Margin="0,10,80,0"
                        Width="100px"
                        Height="70px"
                        />
            </RelativePanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>  
    <MediaElement x:Name="pSong" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="30,30,30,30"
                  RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                  MediaEnded="Mend" />                                            
</Grid>
```

Note that I moved the `MediaElement` after the `ScrollViewer`. The elements defined later in the tree are displayed on top of those before them. Also, I removed the `Canvas.ZIndex` which is usless unless the element is inside a `Canvas`.

Currently the `MediaElement` is not visible (its `Visibility` is set to `Collapsed`).

Now on tap on the panel you show the video:

```
private void TTLStap(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pSong.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Videos/twinkle.mp4");
    pSong.AreTransportControlsEnabled = true; 
    //show the media element
    pSong.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

And in the `MediaEnded` handler you hide it again.

```
public void Mend( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
   pSong.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: You said correctly but my requirement is that if someone tap on image say Tapped="TTLStap" a new background image should be opened and video starts playing above it means on its own panel.